# Adding a links to js and css files within a conditional script in page header

Tags: php, javascript

I want to add something like this to my page header, in order to load a js and css file only if NOT an iPhone/iPad:

```
if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))
{
    //Link to js file
    //Link to css file
}
```

The first line works fine, I've tested it by pasting in a script, but I'm not sure how to get the files linked... especially as I'd like the js and css links to start with the WP template tag `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>`

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You could check the navigator server-side (so directly within PHP) and use the WP api to add JS and CSS files. Otherwise you need to pass the directory URI as a JS variable into the page and re-use it there conditionally.

Comment: Not the answer, but that if statement is actually checking that its `not an iPhone` or `is an iPod`. `if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i) || navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i)))` might be what you want

Comment: possible duplicate of [Passing Variables from PHP to JS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8775680/passing-variables-from-php-to-js)

Comment: try out [this link](http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml), that'll do i guess

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's better to check the user agent using PHP, since it's easier to then add the right HTML tags to load the right css and js files.

```
<?php if ( !preg_match( '/iPhone/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) && !preg_match( '/iPod/', $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ) ): ?>
  <link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/style.css">
  <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Doing it using just javascript would add unneeded complexity, and need you to use a js loader as RequireJS http://requirejs.org/

Answer (score 5):

```
<?php
    if (!preg_match("{iPhone|iPod}i",$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
    {
       echo '<script src="yourscript.js"></script>';
       echo '<link href="yourstyle.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks Tomas. That adds the code, but what about the `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>` part? e.g. the js link needs to be `<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri(); ?>/yourscript.js`

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
<?php if(!(navigator.userAgent.match(/iPhone/i)) || (navigator.userAgent.match(/iPod/i))) : ?>
    <link href="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/main.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" >
    <script src="<?php echo get_stylesheet_directory_uri() ?>/main.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<?php endif ?>
```

Comment: Thanks seferov, but that breaks the page!